# Can be their an extension to save pages in as offline in the browser itself?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, browser, save, firefox-addon, offline

Can be their an extension  to save pages in as  offline in the browser itself?

Serached for many extension counted find any

just like an youtube offline or also local offline the page to be saved in browser(techincally on local drive but an for user it should be accessed via browser)

Comment: Right click and save as. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking questions. Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @NorioYamamoto: 'Save As' doesn't work in many cases, because it regenerates the page, which can give issues with captcha/etc. The OP's question doesn't make much sense in English, though.